# Move Stream to Beginning of File

Tags: file, d

If I open a file with mode a+ (for reading and writing), how do I set the stream back at the start of the file in D?

What I want to do is read the file, and than continuously keep updating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File.seek(0) should do it:

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html#seek

works like C's fseek